# Spark json file is throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting below error at this line: val eventDS = sparkSession.sqlContext.read.json("src/main/resources/output/intermediateOutput.json")

```
    val sparkSession: SparkSession = InjectorProvider.get().getInstance(classOf[SparkSession])
    import sparkSession.implicits._
  try {
    val eventDS = sparkSession.sqlContext.read.json("src/main/resources/output/intermediateOutput.json")
    eventDS.createOrReplaceTempView("events")
  } catch {
    case e: Exception =>
      // Log the exception
      println("Exception occurred while reading intermediate JSON event: " + e.getMessage)
  }
```

This is the error I am getting on reading json file

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 17418 out of bounds for length 206

This is the json event at the above location:

```
[
  {
    "modelName": "test",
    "docKey": "a9f1900b-19fe-41cd-8cdb-7eb581d06421#1700638844739",
    "isUpdate": true,
    "isUpsert": false,
    "etlTime": 1700638844739,
    "etlTimeHuman": "2023-11-22T07:40:44.739000",
    "accountId": "12312",
    "timeStamp": 1695686400000,
    "doc": {
      "campaignId": 1233,
      "engagementId": 3244,
      "skillId": 3424,
      "rule": "Show Campaign 1 if online agents is greater than 0",
      "action": "SHOW",
      "actionCount": 1,
      "timeInState": 51703,
      "eventType": "Ereport",
      "reportTime": "00"
    }
  },
  {
    "modelName": "test",
    "docKey": "816fdbc7-7797-4ea1-b873-a309be84865a#1700638844753",
    "isUpdate": true,
    "isUpsert": false,
    "etlTime": 1700638844753,
    "etlTimeHuman": "2023-11-22T07:40:44.753000",
    "accountId": "12312",
    "timeStamp": 1695686400000,
    "doc": {
      "campaignId": 12312,
      "engagementId": 12312,
      "skillId": 4233,
      "rule": "fasdfa",
      "action": "HIDE",
      "actionCount": 1,
      "timeInState": 81704,
      "eventType": "Ereport",
      "reportTime": "00"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val sparkSession: SparkSession = InjectorProvider.get().getInstance(classOf[SparkSession])

try {
  // Define the schema for your JSON data
  val schema = StructType(Seq(
    StructField("modelName", StringType),
    StructField("docKey", StringType),
    StructField("isUpdate", BooleanType),
    // ... add other fields as per your JSON structure
  ))

  // Read the JSON file with the specified schema
  val eventDS: DataFrame = sparkSession.read.schema(schema).json("src/main/resources/output/intermediateOutput.json")

  eventDS.createOrReplaceTempView("events")
} catch {
  case e: Exception =>
    // Log the exception
    println("Exception occurred while reading intermediate JSON event: " + e.getMessage)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**